Find the closest value in a list less than or greater than a input value
I have a dataframe of input values and a list of bin limits. I want to have two additional columns containing the low bin limit and the high bin limit (bin may be the wrong word here, but hopefully you'll see what I'm after).
I've tried to use bisect but it doesn't seem to work on arrays, so I suppose I could loop it but my real DF is 600k rows.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bisect import *

bin_limits = [0,25000,50000,75000,100000,150000,250000,500000,1000000]

df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [12500,50123,165687,500001,150000,1000000],})

df['lower_bin'] = ""
df['upper_bin'] = ""

df['lower_bin'] = bin_limits[bisect_left(bin_limits, df['number']) - 1]
df['upper_bin'] = bin_limits[bisect_right(bin_limits, df['number'])]

I get the error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
The resulting DF should look like this:
df_final = pd.DataFrame({
    'number':    [12500,50123,165687, 500001,150000,1000000],
    'lower_bin': [25000,50000,150000, 500000,150000, 500000],
    'upper_bin': [25000,75000,250000,1000000,250000,1000000]
})


Any solution to this problem will have to inspect every row, so that isn't an argument against you writing your own loop.

Note that your output is a bit ambiguous, the first lower should be 0, and whether you want to include the left or right boundary is unclear (150000 and 100000 are handled differently in your example).

Finding a values in a list of bins is typically achieved with cut. You can combine this with an IntervalIndex to get the left/right values:
i = pd.IntervalIndex(pd.cut(df['number'], bins=bin_limits))

df['lower_bin'] = i.left
df['upper_bin'] = i.right

Output:
    number  lower_bin  upper_bin
0    12500          0      25000
1    50123      50000      75000
2   165687     150000     250000
3   500001     500000    1000000
4   150000     100000     150000
5  1000000     500000    1000000


Thanks. This solution works largely as requested however for the example where the 'number' is 150k the lower and upper bins should be 150k and 250k rather than 100k and 150k. How could this be solved?

@Nick_FN you can change cut's right parameter to right=False.

You can achieve this by applying a function to your dataset, setting your limited using bisect_left and bisect_right since this is a column, you need to iterate each element.
Heres the code for what I would do:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

# Define bin limits
bin_limits = [0, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 150000, 250000, 500000, 1000000]

# Create your DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [12500, 50123, 165687, 500001, 150000, 1000000]})

# Function to find the lower and upper bin
def find_bins(x, bins):
    lower_idx = bisect_left(bins, x) - 1
    upper_idx = bisect_right(bins, x)
    
    lower_bin = bins[lower_idx] if lower_idx >= 0 else None
    upper_bin = bins[upper_idx] if upper_idx < len(bins) else None
    
    return pd.Series([lower_bin, upper_bin])

# Apply the function to each element in the 'number' column
df[['lower_bin', 'upper_bin']] = df['number'].apply(find_bins, bins=bin_limits)

print(df)

The output for this code should give you what is shown below.
   number  lower_bin  upper_bin
0   12500      25000      25000
1   50123      50000      75000
2  165687     150000     250000
3  500001     500000    1000000
4  150000     150000     250000
5 1000000     500000    1000000

As stated prior, the bisect_left(bins, x) - 1 and bisect_right(bins, x) finds the index for the lower and higher bin value respectively. Keep in mind if the lower index is less than 0, since there is no valid lower bin, it will return None. The inverse should also apply such as if the upper index exceeds the limits, it will also return None.
If this does not work, ill re-review answer and edit where nessesary.

Thanks, I like this solution, however contrary to your output where 'number' is equal to a bin limit then I don't get the correct answer. For example if I have a 'number' of 100k and bin limits of 75k, 100k and 150k the it sets lower to 75k and upper to 150k. The lower value should be 100k.

fixed by adding:
lower_bin =  np.where(x in bins, x, lower_bin)
may not be the best fix but seems to work ok as upper bin was fine

if it works it works, doesn't need to be pretty.
